# Custom Y-axis Label in SSRS?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have an SSRS Report I'm trying to create that leverages the charting capabilities within. I have been trying, without avail, to construct custom labels for the Y-axis shown below. I want the "1" to be converted to "a", the "2" to "b" and so forth. I can do utilizing with Data labels but nothing seems to work on the axis. Custom Number formats are ignoring IIF statements when I try that..

Does anyone know how I can convert these numbers below?

[image]

Comment: Why not return the value in your data instead as an additional column? You could do this by using `CHAR`. `CHAR(97)` is `'a'`, so you could do `CHAR(YourColumn + 96)` [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b4bf8bb49c529a0edbababfdee342aa8)

Comment: Hi Larnu - Thanks for the reply. Can I control the sorting then if I do that?

Comment: You can still order by `YourColumn`, @James, yes